# Unable to connect to Canon scanner. Trying from 'sudo simple scan'

Tags: 16.04, scanner, canon

Have looked at previous answers and nothing helps. Ubuntu 16.4. To make things more confusing every 30 attempts it works.

Other functions of printer work Canon MG5550.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried using gscan2pdf from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: I've added that as an answer for others to reference. Perhaps you'd be kind enough to upvote it and accept it.

Comment: My upvote is recorded but not registered as I haven't contributed enough yet...sorry

Comment: Thanks for that. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and keep contributing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gscan2pdf instead downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Centre.